# issue with layout textview alignment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've tried all the layouts but I still have the same problem. I want to align a TextView horizontally but nothing works. In all the layouts available, none has worked. Always having the same picture. It's like having a block on the right that blocks everything.

[Image describing the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alIyB.png)

Can someone help please?

Comment: Please put your xml codes here

Comment: Share the relevant code, In this case the Layout XML of that activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try do it with constraint layout.

Example first:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[first result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeGDx.png)

second example:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieN07.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

this will tell Android to align your TextView to align in center horizontally.

Example

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
```

Also, share your xml code so I can rectify it

Comment: @Unknown  Remove ConstraintLayout and replace it with LinearLayout, then it should work with my suggestion

Comment: also try android:layout_gravity="center"